# Throttle Jquery UI drag event listener, and passing argument using underscore.js or other implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, underscore.js

I have a draggable element which triggers a resize of some component in my application.  I would like to throttle `this.dragAdjust( ui.offset );` using underscore.js or a jquery plugin.  The issue is that I'm not sure how to pass along the argument, `ui.offset`.

```
var self = this;
$("#hs-resizer").draggable( { 
    axis: "y", 
    containment: "parent"//, 
    //drag: function( event, ui ) {
    //    self.dragAdjust( ui.offset );    
    //}
});

$("#hs-resizer").drag( _.throttle( self.dragAdjust, 500 ) );
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do..? Are you trying to resize an element, or do you just want to pass the argument to some other function..?

Comment: I need to pass along how far the element has be dragged to another function which will perform some calculations reconfigure the layout of the page.

Comment: How about `drag: function( event, ui ) { yourFunction( ui.offset ); }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#hs-resizer").draggable( { 
  axis: "y", 
  containment: "parent", 
  drag:  _.throttle(self.dragAdjust, 500 )
});
```

Comment: The issue is that self.dragAdjust needs to know how far the draggable item has moved.  So I pass the argument ui.offset.

Comment: As far as i know, `_.throttle` will return a throttled version of your `self.dragAdjust` method, jquery ui will call this method on `drag` and pass the `event` and `ui` arguments to it, like any other functions passed to the `drag` option. You don't have to manually pass anything.